# Axios generic Post returns wrong type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, axios, typescript-generics

I am trying to return a typed object using the Axios API. I am using the generic type to declare that I am returning an instance of `GetSliceResponse` but unfortunately Axios seems to still return an object of type any.

My code looks like this

```
export class GetSliceResponse 
{
    Success: boolean;
}

Axios.post<GetSliceResponse>("myurl/Get", request).then(o => {
    var expectedResult = (new GetSliceResponse()) instanceof GetSliceResponse;
    //expectedResult = true;
    var unexpectedResult = o.data instanceof GetSliceResponse;
    //unexpectedResult = false;
});
```

The Http response is exactly what you would expect:

```
{"Success":false}
```

As the above code illustrates I can correctly create an instance of my type using the `new` syntax but the Axios data property appears unaffected by the type declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because something has the same properties as the class does not mean it is an instance of the class. In your case the response from the server is probably parsed using `JSON.parse` which will create simple objects. Only objects created using `new GetSliceResponse` will actually be instances of the class.

The type parameter to the post method is meant to help describe the shape of the response but will not actually change the runtime behavior (nor could it, genetics are erased during compilation).

This being said, you can still access the properties of the object as if the object was an instance of the class, the only thing that will not work is `instanceof` and don't expect any method to be present.

If you want to make sure nobody uses `instanceof` by mistake you can make the type am interface instead.

If you really need the class you can create an instance using `new` and use `Object.assign` to assign all fields

```
export class GetSliceResponse 
{
    Success: boolean;
}

Axios.post<GetSliceResponse>("myurl/Get", request).then(o => {
    o = Object.assign(new GetSliceResponse(), o);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Titian, after looking at the source code you are absolutely correct in saying that all its doing is calling JSON.parse. I probably shouldn't have assumed that it was actually doing type casting. Your solution is succinct and works perfectly. Thanks again.